# Convert Python List to Vector<int> in Cython

Tags: python, cython

I need to convert a Python list of ints to vector[int] in a cdef function to call another C function. I tried this:

```
cdef pylist_to_handles(hs):
    cdef vector[int] o_vect
    for h in hs:
        o_vect.push_back(h)
    return o_vect
```

This should work because I only need to call this from other cdef functions, but I get this error:

> Cannot convert 'vector<int>' to Python object

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you really have is this:

```
cdef object pylist_to_handles(hs):
    ...
    return <object>o_vect
```

If you do not explicitily set a type, it is assumed to be a python object ("object" in code). As you see in the code, you're trying to cast vector[int] to an object, but Cython does not know how to handle that.

Just add a return type in cdef:

```
cdef vector[int] pylist_to_handles(hs):
```

Answer (score 10):

In Cython 0.17 using [libcpp.vector](http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html#standard-library), you can do this:

```
cdef vector[int] vect = hs
```